# How do I set the Initial Directory on an OpenFileDIalog to the users `Downloads` folder in C#

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

Ok so I have an OpenFileDialog and I want to set the initial directory to the users 'Download' folder. This is an internal application and, therefore, I am sure that the user will be using Windows 7.

```
var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

//This doesn't work
ofd.InitialDirectory =
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Downloads");

//This doesn't work either
ofd.InitialDirectory = @"%USERPROFILE%\Downloads";

ofd.Filter = "Zip Files|*.zip";

ofd.ShowDialog();

txtFooBar.Text = ofd.FileName;
```

I have tried the above so far and neither work. No Exception is thrown, it just doesn't set the initial directory to the downloads folder.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloads folder: not special enough?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795023/downloads-folder-not-special-enough)

Comment: Apologies, this worked perfectly for me. Thankyou Hans.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1175250/333404

**UPDATE**:

Works for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3795159/333404

```
  private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.InitialDirectory = GetDownloadsPath();
            ofd.Filter = "Zip Files|*.zip";
            ofd.ShowDialog();
        }

        public static string GetDownloadsPath() {
            string path = null;
            if (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6) {
                IntPtr pathPtr;
                int hr = SHGetKnownFolderPath(ref FolderDownloads, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out pathPtr);
                if (hr == 0) {
                    path = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pathPtr);
                    Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pathPtr);
                    return path;
                }
            }
            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal));
            path = Path.Combine(path, "Downloads");
            return path;
        }

        private static Guid FolderDownloads = new Guid("374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B");
        [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath(ref Guid id, int flags, IntPtr token, out IntPtr path);
```

Comment: Hmm, other directory's work ok, for example, Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) works fine, but when I try and go one step further, the Initial Directory just reverts to the root of my C drive.

Answer (score 14):

I was able to use the environment to call directly but I had to add `ToString()` to the end.  It didn't work until I added it.

```
saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```

Comment: Instead of rejecting the edits to my comment, I will say that when I posted this originally in 2015, I was required by my compiler to us ToString() to get this function to work.  in VS2019, it works just fine.  That was my experience and that is why I posted that comment.

Comment: This answer doesn't help because it deals with the "Desktop" folder, not the "Downloads" folder that the questions asks for

Answer (score 1):

The **Downloads** folder has a localized name and anyway is never a good idea to assume a specific relative location of a well known folder (even if it's well documented) because it may be changed by user settings too.

Unlucky the `SpecialFolder` enumeration doesn't contain every known folder so you have to use a little bit of interop, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776912%28v=vs.10%29.aspx). From that page we can find the [full list of known folders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378457%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), what you're looking for is **FOLDERID_Downloads**, because the [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762249%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function requires a GUID you have to declare somewhere that constant. Your code will be then something like this:

```
static class ShellHelpers
{
 public static string GetDownloadsFolder()
 {
  string path;
  int result = SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Downloads, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out path);
  if (result != NOERROR)
   Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(result); // You may fallback to another method or folder

  return path;
 }

 private static readonly Guid FOLDERID_Downloads = new Guid("374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B");
 private static readonly int NOERROR = 0;

 [DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
 private static extern int SHGetKnownFolderPath([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] Guid rfid, uint dwFlags, IntPtr hToken, out string pszPath);
}
```

*Please note you can use the P/Invoke signature you prefer (someone uses a StringBuilder, someone else an IntPtr).*

Answer (score 0):

I used @tim's answer and it worked fine. Only I used it without the `ToString()` method and directly with the `Path.Combine()` method.

```
private OpenFileDialog openFileDialog;
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Downloads");
```

Answer (score -1):

Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + @"" + "Downloads"

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
ofd.InitialDirectory = @"%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\Downloads";
```