# Save openFileDialog1.FileName to Properties.Settings

Tags: c#

I have ­­­­WFA with next structure:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.­­­­ComponentModel;
using Sy­­­­stem.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<string> urls = new List<string>();
        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                urls.Clear();
                foreach (string url in File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                    urls.Add(url);
                label2.Text = urls.Count.ToString();
            }
        }

        List<string> links = new List<string>();
        private void open2FileToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open­­­­FileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
            openFile­­­­Dialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                links.Clear();
                foreach (string link in File.ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1.FileName))
                    links.Add(link);
                label4.Text = links.Count.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Scree­­­­n of desi­­­­gn:

http://screenshotuploader.com/i/01/k0tpbijza.png

I need to save to propeties.settings a path of files, opened in openFileDialog.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `RestoreDirectory` to true as well as the `InitialDirectory` property.

More about that topic: [Setting the initial directory of an SaveFileDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175242/setting-the-initial-directory-of-an-savefiledialog)

Comment: can you kindly tell me why is that so? just interesting.