# Does OpenFileDialog InitialDirectory not accept relative path?

Tags: c#, relative-path, openfiledialog

`dialog` is an `OpenFileDialog` class object, and I am using `ShowDialog()` method.

When I use path containing relative path, like:

```
dialog.InitialDirectory = "..\\abcd";
dialog.InitialDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "..\\abcd";
```

`ShowDialog()` crashes; what I only can do is giving a definite path, starting with a disk drive:

```
dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\ABC\\DEF\\abcd";
```

In this case I want the path to be 1 level up of my .exe's current directory, and then downward to directory `abcd`.
The .exe's current path can be found by `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`, which is perfectly fine, but I cant go on with `".."`)

The directory hierarchy is like:

```
ABC
    DEF 
        abcd (where I want to go)
        defg (where .exe is at)
```

So, is there any method to use `"..\\"` with `InitialDirectory`?
Or I must use definite path with it?
Thanks!

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175242/setting-the-initial-directory-of-an-savefiledialog/1175250#1175250

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found my own answer!!

```
string CombinedPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..\\abcd");
dialog.InitialDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(CombinedPath);
```

Answer (score 4):

See if the following gets you the path you're looking for:

```
dialog.InitialDirectory
  = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()), "abcd");
```

---

The call to [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) strips off the last portion of the path, after the last directory separator, whether it's a file name or folder name.

Comment: The issue was that adding a relative path like ..\abcd doesn't work. It still won't with the above approach; rather check Marson Mao's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be

```
openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,@"..\YourSubDirectoryName");
```