# How do I know which folder Save As… will start in?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want to avoid opening the Save As dialog in one specific folder. If I open a file from that folder then do a Save As…, it starts in that same folder (as expected). I thought I could just examine `InitialDirectory` after calling `new SaveFileDialog()` and change it if necessary, but it is an empty string.

`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns the folder containing the executable.

```
var dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
Console.WriteLine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()); // Prints "Z:\Documents\Projects\ProjectName\bin\x64\Debug"
Console.WriteLine(dialog.InitialDirectory); // Prints empty string
```

How do I ask Windows (7 or 10) which folder the Save As… dialog will start in?

**Edit**

This is a completely different question than "How do I set the initial directory?". I want to know what the initial directory is going to be before the dialog opens so that I can change it only in the case where it is going to be one specific directory.

Comment: have you checked this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175242/setting-the-initial-directory-of-an-savefiledialog

Comment: The initial directory is stored on an application basis somewhere. Not in plaintext in the registry anyway, as far as a quick test showed. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ComDlg32\OpenSavePidlMRU` contains some fragments. `FileDialog.InitialDirectory` doesn't get seeded with it anyway, it appears to be determined _after_ you call `ShowDialog()`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks. That got me close enough that I was able to find the answer with some searching. The most recent directory is in `LastVisitedPidlMRU`. Interpreting that data is a different issue.

Answer (score -1):

I assume that you want the savefiledialog to start from the folder you want

Try this to change the initial directory to whatever you want

```
dialog.InitialDirectory="C:\Users\Your_Name\Desktop\";
```