# How do I get SaveFileDialog to pop up and redirect to a selected folder?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I get the `SaveFileDialog` to pop up and redirect to a selected folder? I have tried what I can but I've only established to get the program to open the File Explorer and redirect to the folder without the `SaveFileDialog` working.

This is my code:

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stream myStream;
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            myStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you tried.  You should be able to just set the `InitialDirectory` property to the folder that you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the initial directory of an SaveFileDialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175242/setting-the-initial-directory-of-an-savefiledialog)

Answer (score 0):

Just set your initial directory

For example:

```
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\<username>\Desktop";
```